# what's a git equivalent to 'p4 annotate -a'?

Tags: git, perforce, annotate

perforce has a very useful command that prints out all revisions of a file, with annotations indicating what versions contained each line in the file.  For example, say I create a file foo, check it in, and then check in two subsequent changes to the file.  Here are the three versions of foo:

```
aaa            aaa           aaa
bbb            bbb           bbb
ccc            ccc           ccc
               ddd           ddd
               eee           fff
               fff
```

Here is what p4 annotate -a prints:

```
1-3: aaa
1-3: bbb
1-3: ccc
2-3: ddd
2-2: eee
2-3: fff
```

I see the entire history of foo, with annotations indicating which versions contained each line.

AFAICT, git blame only gives the last version containing each line.  git log with pickaxe only prints lines that match the pattern, and gives the commit messages rather than lines in the file itself.

Is there any way to do something similar to the above perforce command in git?

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing directly equivalent in Git - since Git doesn't have a linear history, something like `1-3` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: "git log -S 'search_string' file" uses git pickaxe functionality, and does something with the git directed acyclic graph relevant to "file" as I understand it.  I was hoping for something like that, but with output in terms of file lines instead of git commit messages.

Comment: `git log -S` finds commits that introduce or remove the specified string. It's just a history filter. You might be able to pipe the specified revisions into `git blame` and then `grep` for the lines in the blame output that also contain the string...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git blame` for that I suppose -- it will show the source commit for each line.

This probably isn't exactly what you want, but it's a step in the right direction. You could combine that output with the output from `git log` and build the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

how about use `git annotate` , it can output detail annotations for each file